# Mysql join vs having duplicate

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I read today this blog post http://www.andrewrollins.com/2009/06/21/mysql-join-performance/ about join performance. As seen, join could cost performance in some way.

Let's take now an example of two tables, user_profile and user_gallery.

```
user_profile
user_id | avatar | nickname | ...

user_gallery
image_id | user_id | image | caption | is_avatar
```

On page browse users, users are listed with their nickname and avatar image.

I can get image in users list with join

```
INNER JOIN user_gallery ON user_gallery.user_id=user_profile.user_id WHERE user_gallery.is_avatar=1
```

or I can put to **avatar** field an image path. In this case, I don't need to use **is_avatar** field and I have all data needed to display users in table user_profile. So no extra join is needed. But since avatar image is part of user gallery, this would mean value of **avatar** is also in user_gallery table, so one duplicate value.

Is it really worth to strictly follow normalization rules which could cost performance, having in mind this exact case? What would be better in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the need for joining to `user_profile` if you're not needing columns from it.  Otherwise, I don't see how the user_profile.avatar field works when there could be multiple images for a given user profile...

Comment: One user can have only 1 avatar and avatar image is displayed in user list page (browse users). In browse users it is a list of users with their nickname, age and avatar image. On browse users page, avatar is link to user profile. I am not sure what you mean by not needing columns from it. I need in browse users page data about nickname, age and avatar.

When you are on user profile page, you can also see user gallery. Avatar image become automatically also part of user gallery when user registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical choice seems to me to abandon the `is_avatar` field and just have `user_profile.avatar` reference an `image_id`...

Comment: This is based on sane normalization principles, which in my opinion should always be the first concern until you know performance is a problem. It shouldn't be costly in this case, as you'll only be doing one extra read of a user_gallery record indexed by its primary key.

Comment: I need to have in mind that later I may decide to also display city, this would be extra join because city names are in another table.

Comment: And I already use another join with user_account table, because I need to display only users that has is_active field value 1. So that is why I am concerned about limiting joins as much as possible.